# How to find the exact center of a String?

Tags: android

How to find the exact pixel center of a String?
I need this for drawing onto a canvas.

Comment: Do you mean the exact center of a TextView that's displaying a string?

Comment: No, a string because I am using a canvas

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer rather than posting an answer as part of your question. I've rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use the paint.measureText( "String" ), it will give the number of pixels required to display the string.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the answer but probably can solve your problem.

Paint has setTextAlign method. If you set

```
paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
```

`drawText(text, x, y, paint)` will paint text with the (x,y) in the center.

Comment: It is possible to find the Vertical center?